# Не выходит вызвать метод принадлежащий Activity из фрагмента

Tags: android-sdk, android, android-fragment

У меня есть фрагмент:

```
        public class NewDictionaryInput_Fragment extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_dictionary, null);
                v.findViewById(R.id.btnOK).setOnClickListener(this);
                return v;
            }

            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText etDictionary = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et1);
                SelectDictionary sd = (SelectDictionary) getActivity();
                Log.i("APP", "1");
                sd.addNewDictionary(etDictionary.getText().toString());
                Log.i("APP", "2");
                dismiss();
            }
    }
```

И `Activity` (оставил только метод):

```
 public class SelectDictionary extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    int i = 0;
    String[] dictionaries;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select_dictionary);
    }

    void addNewDictionary(String dictionary) {
        DBHelper mDatabaseHelper = new DBHelper(this, "dictionaries", "Dictionaries");
        SQLiteDatabase mSqLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues newDictionary = new ContentValues();

        // Если словарь пустой или содержит только пробел - удаляю
        if (dictionary.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Нельзя задать пустое имя", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SelectDictionary.class);
            startActivity(i);
            this.finish();
            return;
        }

        if (dictionary.equals(" ")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Нельзя задать пустое имя", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SelectDictionary.class);
            startActivity(i);
            this.finish();
            return;
        }

        // Закидываю в словари
        newDictionary.put("dictionary", dictionary.replace(' ', '_'));
        mSqLiteDatabase.insert("dictionaries", null, newDictionary);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, SelectDictionary.class);
        startActivity(i);
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Ошибка выскакивает во время выполнения `sd.addNewDictionary(etDictionary.getText().toString());`

Вывод `logcat` с лог уровнем `error` (выкладываю все, так как незнаю, что именно нужно :)):

```
10-09 00:40:15.648: ERROR/NativeCrypto(7400): ssl=0x63411340 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x63030938 arg=0x0
10-09 00:40:15.649: ERROR/NativeCrypto(7400): ssl=0x63411340 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
10-09 00:41:52.459: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(780): Object tried to add another callback
10-09 00:41:52.459: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(780): java.lang.Exception: Called by
10-09 00:41:52.459: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(780):     at com.android.keyguard.KeyguardUpdateMonitor.registerCallback(KeyguardUpdateMonitor.java:1104)
10-09 00:41:52.459: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(780):     at com.android.keyguard.KeyguardSelectorView.onResume(KeyguardSelectorView.java:340)
10-09 00:41:52.459: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(780):     at com.android.keyguard.KeyguardHostView.onScreenTurnedOn(KeyguardHostView.java:1298)
10-09 00:41:52.459: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(780):     at com.android.keyguard.KeyguardViewManager.onScreenTurnedOn(KeyguardViewManager.java:500)
10-09 00:41:52.459: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(780):     at com.android.keyguard.KeyguardViewMediator.handleNotifyScreenOn(KeyguardViewMediator.java:1648)
10-09 00:41:52.459: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(780):     at com.android.keyguard.KeyguardViewMediator.access$2500(KeyguardViewMediator.java:115)
10-09 00:41:52.459: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(780):     at com.android.keyguard.KeyguardViewMediator$4.handleMessage(KeyguardViewMediator.java:1317)
10-09 00:41:52.459: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(780):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
10-09 00:41:52.459: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(780):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
10-09 00:41:52.459: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(780):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
10-09 00:41:52.459: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 00:41:52.459: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-09 00:41:52.459: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(780):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
10-09 00:41:52.459: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(780):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
10-09 00:41:52.459: ERROR/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(780):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 00:41:52.500: ERROR/AudioMTKHardware(142): setCommonParameters() still have param.size() = 1, remain param = "screen_state=on"
10-09 00:41:52.648: ERROR/panhongyang(870): liantong 2g level=4 asu=31 dBm=-51
10-09 00:41:52.651: ERROR/panhongyang(675): liantong 2g level=4 asu=31 dBm=-51
10-09 00:41:52.665: ERROR/SpecailDayAlarmManager(19729): screen on...
10-09 00:41:52.668: ERROR/lifen(780): readNVram()=UA
10-09 00:41:52.674: ERROR/lifen(780): readNVram()=UA
10-09 00:41:52.681: ERROR/panhongyang(780): liantong 2g level=4 asu=31 dBm=-51
10-09 00:41:52.683: ERROR/panhongyang(780): liantong 2g level=4 asu=31 dBm=-51
10-09 00:41:52.712: ERROR/CellLocation(675): create GsmCellLocation
10-09 00:41:52.714: ERROR/CellLocation(2074): create GsmCellLocation
10-09 00:41:52.721: ERROR/CellLocation(2074): create GsmCellLocation
10-09 00:41:52.729: ERROR/lifen(780): readNVram()=UA
10-09 00:41:52.732: ERROR/lifen(780): readNVram()=UA
10-09 00:41:52.740: ERROR/CellLocation(675): create GsmCellLocation
10-09 00:41:52.762: ERROR/CellLocation(2074): create GsmCellLocation
10-09 00:41:52.795: ERROR/RemoteViews(675): ANR Warning,RemoteViews can only be used once ,if not ,it may cause ANR in hosts such as Laucher,SystemUI. keys for search <ANR Exception MSG   History>
10-09 00:41:52.914: ERROR/lights(675): [write_int] open patch =/sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness
10-09 00:41:52.914: ERROR/lights(675): [write_int] open fd = 243,value = 212
10-09 00:41:52.914: ERROR/lights(675): [write_int] write amt=4
10-09 00:41:53.492: ERROR/(675): Could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd'
10-09 00:41:53.492: ERROR/(675): error : 2, No such file or directory
10-09 00:41:53.553: ERROR/(675): Could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd'
10-09 00:41:53.553: ERROR/(675): error : 2, No such file or directory
10-09 00:41:53.600: ERROR/Zygote(12336): Zygote:  error closing descriptor
10-09 00:41:53.600: ERROR/Zygote(12336): libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
10-09 00:41:53.600: ERROR/Zygote(12336):     at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
10-09 00:41:53.600: ERROR/Zygote(12336):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
10-09 00:41:53.600: ERROR/Zygote(12336):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.closeServerSocket(ZygoteInit.java:220)
10-09 00:41:53.600: ERROR/Zygote(12336):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleChildProc(ZygoteConnection.java:879)
10-09 00:41:53.600: ERROR/Zygote(12336):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:242)
10-09 00:41:53.600: ERROR/Zygote(12336):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:700)
10-09 00:41:53.600: ERROR/Zygote(12336):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
10-09 00:41:53.600: ERROR/Zygote(12336):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 00:41:53.694: ERROR/(142): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
10-09 00:41:53.868: ERROR/(142): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
10-09 00:41:53.870: ERROR/(142): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
10-09 00:42:08.030: ERROR/cutils-trace(12370): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-09 00:42:08.182: ERROR/(142): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
10-09 00:42:08.201: ERROR/(142): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
10-09 00:42:08.252: ERROR/memtrack(12370): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
10-09 00:42:08.252: ERROR/android.os.Debug(12370): failed to load memtrack module: -2
10-09 00:42:08.924: ERROR/cutils-trace(12394): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-09 00:42:09.110: ERROR/memtrack(12394): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
10-09 00:42:09.110: ERROR/android.os.Debug(12394): failed to load memtrack module: -2
10-09 00:42:09.203: ERROR/(675): Could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd'
10-09 00:42:09.203: ERROR/(675): error : 2, No such file or directory
10-09 00:42:09.244: ERROR/(675): Could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd'
10-09 00:42:09.244: ERROR/(675): error : 2, No such file or directory
10-09 00:42:09.250: ERROR/Zygote(12405): Zygote:  error closing descriptor
10-09 00:42:09.250: ERROR/Zygote(12405): libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
10-09 00:42:09.250: ERROR/Zygote(12405):     at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
10-09 00:42:09.250: ERROR/Zygote(12405):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
10-09 00:42:09.250: ERROR/Zygote(12405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.closeServerSocket(ZygoteInit.java:220)
10-09 00:42:09.250: ERROR/Zygote(12405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleChildProc(ZygoteConnection.java:879)
10-09 00:42:09.250: ERROR/Zygote(12405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:242)
10-09 00:42:09.250: ERROR/Zygote(12405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:700)
10-09 00:42:09.250: ERROR/Zygote(12405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
10-09 00:42:09.250: ERROR/Zygote(12405):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 00:42:09.305: ERROR/(675): Could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd'
10-09 00:42:09.305: ERROR/(675): error : 2, No such file or directory
10-09 00:42:09.437: ERROR/(675): Could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd'
10-09 00:42:09.437: ERROR/(675): error : 2, No such file or directory
10-09 00:42:13.713: ERROR/RemoteViews(675): ANR Warning,RemoteViews can only be used once ,if not ,it may cause ANR in hosts such as Laucher,SystemUI. keys for search <ANR Exception MSG   History>
10-09 00:42:13.714: ERROR/RemoteViews(675): ANR Warning,RemoteViews can only be used once ,if not ,it may cause ANR in hosts such as Laucher,SystemUI. keys for search <ANR Exception MSG   History>
10-09 00:42:15.027: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12405): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 00:42:15.027: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12405): Process: com.example.dictionarydemo_2, PID: 12405
10-09 00:42:15.027: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12405): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-09 00:42:15.027: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12405):     at com.example.dictionarydemo_2.NewDictionaryInput_Fragment.onClick(NewDictionaryInput_Fragment.java:27)
10-09 00:42:15.027: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12405):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
10-09 00:42:15.027: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12405):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
10-09 00:42:15.027: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12405):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
10-09 00:42:15.027: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12405):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
10-09 00:42:15.027: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12405):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
10-09 00:42:15.027: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
10-09 00:42:15.027: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 00:42:15.027: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-09 00:42:15.027: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
10-09 00:42:15.027: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
10-09 00:42:15.027: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12405):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 00:42:15.558: ERROR/(675): Could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd'
10-09 00:42:15.558: ERROR/(675): error : 2, No such file or directory
10-09 00:42:15.745: ERROR/(675): Could not open '/data/data/hotplug/cmd'
10-09 00:42:15.746: ERROR/(675): error : 2, No such file or directory
10-09 00:42:19.828: ERROR/NotificationService(675): n=0
10-09 00:42:19.828: ERROR/NotificationService(675): mLights.size()=0
10-09 00:42:20.781: ERROR/lights(675): [write_int] open patch =/sys/class/leds/button-backlight/brightness
10-09 00:42:20.781: ERROR/lights(675): [write_int] open fd = -1,value = 255
10-09 00:42:21.171: ERROR/(142): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
10-09 00:42:21.207: ERROR/(142): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
10-09 00:42:21.482: ERROR/(142): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
10-09 00:42:21.496: ERROR/(142): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
10-09 00:42:21.592: ERROR/(142): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
10-09 00:42:21.604: ERROR/(142): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
10-09 00:42:21.605: ERROR/(142): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
10-09 00:42:24.164: ERROR/lights(675): [write_int] open patch =/sys/class/leds/button-backlight/brightness
10-09 00:42:24.164: ERROR/lights(675): [write_int] open fd = -1,value = 0
10-09 00:42:24.600: ERROR/lights(675): [write_int] open patch =/sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness
10-09 00:42:24.600: ERROR/lights(675): [write_int] open fd = 243,value = 0
10-09 00:42:24.600: ERROR/lights(675): [write_int] write amt=2
10-09 00:42:24.651: ERROR/KeyguardHostView(780): KeyguardHostView()
10-09 00:42:24.750: ERROR/AudioMTKHardware(142): setCommonParameters() still have param.size() = 1, remain param = "screen_state=off"
10-09 00:42:24.772: ERROR/(142): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
10-09 00:42:24.828: ERROR/(142): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
10-09 00:42:24.948: ERROR/lifen(780): readNVram()=UA
10-09 00:42:24.951: ERROR/lifen(780): readNVram()=UA
10-09 00:42:25.084: ERROR/lifen(780): readNVram()=UA
10-09 00:42:25.087: ERROR/lifen(780): readNVram()=UA
10-09 00:42:25.093: ERROR/lifen(780): readNVram()=UA
10-09 00:42:25.096: ERROR/lifen(780): readNVram()=UA
10-09 00:42:25.101: ERROR/lifen(780): readNVram()=UA
10-09 00:42:25.104: ERROR/lifen(780): readNVram()=UA
10-09 00:42:25.109: ERROR/lifen(780): readNVram()=UA
10-09 00:42:25.112: ERROR/lifen(780): readNVram()=UA
10-09 00:42:25.116: ERROR/lifen(780): readNVram()=UA
10-09 00:42:25.119: ERROR/lifen(780): readNVram()=UA
10-09 00:42:25.305: ERROR/SpecailDayAlarmManager(19729): screen off...
```

Изначально я хотел все это провернуть в фрагменте, но не было контекста, который нужен при создании БД, но с этим я разберусь потом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `NPE`. Скорее всего `EditText` равен `null`;

Что неудивительно, т.к. вы ищете его в переменной `v`. А это кнопка. Вряд ли в ней есть он... Скорее всего вам поможет вынос `EditText` в переменную класса, нахождение его в `onCreateView()` и дальнейшее обращение к переменной класса в методе `onClick()`.

Comment: Хм... Возможно, но я не могу проверить это! При попытке проверить ``EditText`` на пустоту путем:

``if (etDictionary.getText().length() == 0) {
   Log.i("APP", "ПУСТО!!!");
  }`` — программа вылетает. Но как так?

Comment: Вам надо проверить не пуст ли текст в `EditText`, а не является ли `EditText` равным `null`. `if(etDictionary==null){Log.i("APP", "EditText у нас null!!!11 Как же так?!")};`

Comment: Вы в фрагменте, в `onClick`, `EditText` ищете в переменной `v`. А это кнопка. Вряд ли в ней есть он... Скорее всего вам поможет вынос `EditText` в переменную класса, нахождение его в `onCreateView()` и дальнейшее обращение к переменной класса в методе `onClick`

Comment: Оп! Он ``null``. :\ Спасибо! :D

Comment: Заработало через ``etDictionary = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et_1);`` в ``onCreateView()``, но почему? Когда ``v`` стала кнопкой?

Comment: В методе `onClick(View v)` в качестве аргумента передаётся `View` на который вы нажали. В вашем случае это кнопка.

Comment: И снова меня погубила моя невнимательность...

Comment: Со временем пройдёт)

Comment: Сейчас пойду переносить метод в фрагмент... Так что скоро вернусь :), при чем без лога. Я установил Genymotion, a он почему-то лог не выдает.